# find array of objects with array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I've been trying to do this function for two days and I'm not succeeding. I would like the function to return me the objects that satisfy the filter array. The problem is that I would like it to return only objects that satisfy all filters.

My array of filters:

```
const myFiltersIngredients = ['farinha', 'frango']
```

My array of objects:

```
    const myRecipes = [
  {
    name: 'torta da vovo',
    ingredients: [
      {
        ingredient: 'farinha',
        ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
        ingredientQuantity: 500
      },
      {
        ingredient: 'frango',
        ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
        ingredientQuantity: 500
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'biscoito',
    ingredients: [
      {
        ingredient: 'farinha',
        ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
        ingredientQuantity: 500
      },
      {
        ingredient: 'manteiga',
        ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
        ingredientQuantity: 500
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Use the `Array.prototype.every()` method to test that every ingredient is matched, and `Array.protoyype.some()` to tell whether any of the ingredients in a recipe uses an ingredient.

Comment: Something like `myRecipes.filter(({ingredients}) => myFiltersIngredients.every(myfilter => ingredients.map(({ingredient}) => ingredient).includes(myfilter)));`

Comment: Thank you both, everything is working!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myFiltersIngredients = ['farinha', 'frango'];

const myRecipes = [{
        name: 'torta da vovo',
        ingredients: [{
                ingredient: 'farinha',
                ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
                ingredientQuantity: 500
            },
            {
                ingredient: 'frango',
                ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
                ingredientQuantity: 500
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'biscoito',
        ingredients: [{
                ingredient: 'farinha',
                ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
                ingredientQuantity: 500
            },
            {
                ingredient: 'manteiga',
                ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
                ingredientQuantity: 500
            }
        ]
    }
];

const myFiltered = myRecipes.filter(({
    ingredients
}) => myFiltersIngredients.every(myfilter => ingredients.map(({
    ingredient
}) => ingredient).includes(myfilter)));

console.log( myFiltered );
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this small demo helps point you in the right direction.

Here is a link to the [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) array method documentation.

As a brief explanation:

The `.filter` method takes a function as an argument, and will execute the function with each object in the array. The function will return either true or false. The array returned by `.filter` will be all the items in the array that returned true based on the function provided.

The `.every` method takes a function as an argument, and returns true if every item in the array, when passed to the function argument, will returns true.

In my code I first state that I want to filter all the recipes, and return the filtered array into a variable. The function that is passed as an argument only has one line, which checks the object to make sure that every ingredient associated with that object is included in the `myFiltersIngredients`  array.

```js
const myFiltersIngredients = ['farinha', 'frango'];

const myRecipes = [
  {
    name: 'torta da vovo',
    ingredients: [
      {
        ingredient: 'farinha',
        ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
        ingredientQuantity: 500
      },
      {
        ingredient: 'frango',
        ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
        ingredientQuantity: 500
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'biscoito',
    ingredients: [
      {
        ingredient: 'farinha',
        ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
        ingredientQuantity: 500
      },
      {
        ingredient: 'manteiga',
        ingredientUnit: 'grama(s)',
        ingredientQuantity: 500
      }
    ]
  }
];

const filteredRecipes = myRecipes.filter(o => {
  return o.ingredients.every(
    ({ingredient}) => myFiltersIngredients.includes(ingredient)
  );
});

console.log(filteredRecipes);
```

Comment: If someone has an issue with my answer I would love to hear about it 

Comment: It's really fast answer hahahaha.. Thanks thanks thanks

Comment: No problem  If you want me to explain any of it let me know, thought it should be pretty straight forward 

Comment: actually I'm not familiar with using array methods inside other array methods. But I think I understand hahaha (y)

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation and links to the documentation for `.filter` and `.every`, please let me know if you would like any further clarification